# Display entries that start with ! first in UITableViewCell when data comes from NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, firebase

I'm working with Firebase. I get data from Firebase that contains names. If the name starts with an `!` it's important so it gets another colour and should be shown first. The colour change works without problems, but I don't really know how to do the sorting.

With Firebase I get the data and add it to the `UITableView` but now I also want to show the ones with an `!` first. How would be my approach? This is how I show the `UITableViewCell`

The data contains only the title that starts with an `!`.

```
NSArray *tempKeys                   = [dictionaryFinishedProjects allKeys];
NSString *tempIdentifier            = [tempKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *CellIdentifier     = @"Cell";

CustomButton *stateButton           = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
stateButton.projectButtonIdentifier = tempIdentifier;
stateButton.frame                   = CGRectMake(5.0f, 10.0f, 24.0f, 24.0f);
[stateButton setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter];
[stateButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter];
[stateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(updateState:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

CustomCell *cell                    = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:tempIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSString *important                 = @"No";
NSString *projectName               = [dictionaryFinishedProjects objectForKey:[tempKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
if ( [projectName rangeOfString:@"!"].location == NSNotFound ) {
} else {
    important                       = @"Yes";
    projectName                     = [projectName substringFromIndex:1];
    if ( [projectName rangeOfString:@":"].location == NSNotFound ) {}
    else {
        NSArray *splittedProjectName    = [projectName componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSString *temporaryString       = [splittedProjectName objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *removedWhiteSpaces    = [temporaryString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        projectName                     = [splittedProjectName objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text       = removedWhiteSpaces;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text                 = projectName;

    cell.projectCellIdentifier          = tempIdentifier;
    cell.textLabel.frame                = CGRectMake(150.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f);
    UIFont *fontBoldCell                = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    cell.textLabel.font                 = fontBoldCell;
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor      = [UIColor grayColor];
    cell.indentationLevel               = 3;

    Firebase *tempRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", stringRequestUrl, tempIdentifier]];
    [tempRef observeEventType:FEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
        if ( [snapshot.name isEqualToString:@"state"] ) {
            if ( [snapshot.value isEqualToString:@"canceled"]){
                if ( [important isEqualToString:@"No"] ){
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusCancelled forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } else {
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusCancelledRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            } else if ( [snapshot.value isEqualToString:@"done"]){
                if ( [important isEqualToString:@"No"] ){
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusDone forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                } else {
                    [stateButton setBackgroundImage:imageStatusDoneRed forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
    [cell addSubview:stateButton];
    return cell;
```

Comment: Firebase's [ordered data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html) might provide a faster alternative to sorting this client-side. You can assign null/1 priorities to users instead of prefixing them with ! (or in addition to) and get the records back pre-sorted.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that I'm also using `childByAutoId` and when I do it like that

`[[fireBaseProjectReference childByAutoId] updateChildValues:@{@"list":stringProjectIdentifier, @"pos":@"0",@"since":intervalString,@"state":@"new",@"title":@"Neues Projekt"}];
    [[fireBaseProjectReference childByAutoId] setPriority:@3];`

it doesn't seem to work. Seems like `childByAutoId` and `setPriority` don't work together?

Answer (score 2):

Sort your keys based on the objects... that could be done like this:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [dictionaryFinishedProjects keysSortedByValueWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
    BOOL firstImportant = [obj1 hasPrefix:@"!"];
    BOOL secondImportant = [obj2 hasPrefix:@"!"];
    if(firstImportant && !secondImportant) return NSOrderedAscending;
    if(secondImportant && !firstImportant) return NSOrderedDescending;
    return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2];
}];
```

Also you should NOT have sorting/iterating over all data in your cellForRow implementation. Do this only once and save the data in an instance variable. Than just access it in cellForRow...

Note: this implementation also sorts all keys alphabetically.. the ones with ! and the ones without..

Comment: This works almost perfect. Is it also possible to order it firstly by `!` and afterwards by something different ? Like, i have the `unix timestamp` in a variable. Can I check for this after the `!`? So firstly check for Important/Not important and then for timestamp instead of continuing to order alphabetically.

Comment: Yes, just change the sorting method.. You won't get finished code here. Try it yourself. Since the timestamp isn't part of the dictionary you'll need some extra logic. Please accept the answer (click the ckeckmark), if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a priority on the ones you consider important, rather than adding a '!' to the key name. See here for an example: https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html. That will cause Firebase to return them to you in priority order.

If you do want to do more complicated sorting that setting a priority can't handle (maybe set the timestamp as the priority?), then go with what jaydee3 suggested and do the sorting once beforehand with whatever custom sort method you'd like.